# How do you programmatically mute a soundcard record output? (Windows 7)

Tags: c#, windows

I need to programmatically click the MUTE checkbox for a soundcard channel in Windows 7. How can I do this? Ideally, I'd be able to do this using C#.

Comment: So do you want to automate some mouse movements and clicks?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by sound card channel.

If you are trying to mute sounds please refer to this article. You need to invoke windows native functions. Luckily C# has that feature by default you just need to invoke it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719104(v=vs.71).aspx

I would give examples but the best ones are already given by microsoft.